# Hide list item based on boolean true false jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a slide menu in my jsp Page and After login, I am checking whether user is allowed to view element or not from parameters stored in the database. I need to hide the items based on whether the user is allowed to view or not.

My jsp

```
<ul  style = "display:none">
<li><a href="servletName">MyfirstSubmenu</a></li>
<li><a href="servletName1">MyfirstSubmenu1</a></li>
</ul>
```

My dao:extract:

```
public boolean userallowed(username, itemid){
..........................
return true;
}
```

my servlet extract:

```
if(userallowed(username, itemid)){
  session.setAttribute("userallowed", true);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("/mypage.jsp").forward(request, response);
}else{
  request.getRequestDispatcher("/mypage.jsp").forward(request, response);
  session.setAttribute("userallowed", false);
}
```

How Can I write a javascript Function to able to hide elements based on user permissions?

Comment: don't create such fields in JSP instead of hiding because hidden fields can be visible using simple browser plugins such Firefox Firebug Plugin etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simply do this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<c:if test="${true == sessionScope.userallowed}">
<ul>
    <li><a href="servletName">MyfirstSubmenu</a></li>
    <li><a href="servletName1">MyfirstSubmenu1</a></li>
</ul>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Good use of Scriplet in 21st century. Why JSTL and EL is created be experts?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding the element with JavaScript, it's more secure if you put that logic in the JSP file:

```xml
<% if ((boolean) session.getAttribute("userallowed")) { %>
<ul>
    <li><a href="servletName">MyfirstSubmenu</a></li>
    <li><a href="servletName1">MyfirstSubmenu1</a></li>
</ul>
<% } %>
```

Notice how those protected menu items are not sent to the client if they are not allowed to see them.

Also, your servlet code could be simplified a little:

```java
session.setAttribute("userallowed", userallowed(username, itemid));
request.getRequestDispatcher("/mypage.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Good use of Scriplet in 21st century. Why JSTL and EL is created be experts?